# Getting value from JSON object with Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been trying to learn AngularJS recently, and hit a bump in the road with Localstorage i spend so many hours trying to make it save locally, I think that it's working as it should now, but now i would like to print out the data saved local from the JSON array, how can i go about that?

EDIT:

A bit of clarification, What im trying to achieve is getting the information i save in the localstorage out onto the website as a string, so it's readable. hope i'ts more understandable. Thanks in advance

My view.

```
<ion-list>
  <div >
        <ion-item ng-controller='ModalEditCtrl' ng-click="openModal()">
              <div class="thumbnail" style="border:1px black solid">
          </div>
          <div  ng-controller="createPerson"  class="contactinfo" >
            <li ng-repeat="contact in contactdetail.contactinfo">  {{contact.name}} </li>
          </div>

        </ion-item>

  </div>

  <div ng-controller="ModalAddCtrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="openModal()">+++</button>
  </div>

</ion-list>
```

My controller

```
app.controller('createPerson', function ($scope) {
  var id = id_counter = 1;
  $scope.editorEnabled = false;
      $scope.disableEditor = function() {
        $scope.editorEnabled = false;
      };
      $scope.enableEditor = function() {
        $scope.editorEnabled = true;
      };
  $scope.contactinfo = [
    {name: 'test', phone: 1231, email: 'asd@asd.com'}
  ];
  $scope.saveData = function () {
    id_counter += 1;
    $scope.editorEnabled = false;
    $scope.contactinfo.push({
      name: $scope.contactName,
      phone: $scope.contactPhone,
      email: $scope.contactEmail,
      sort_id: id_counter
    });
    //$scope.todoText = ''; //clear the input after adding
    localStorage.setItem('contactinfo', JSON.stringify($scope.contactinfo));
  //  localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));

  }
  $scope.loadData = function () {
    var contacts = localStorage.getItem("contactinfo");
    var contactdetail = JSON.parse(contacts); //
    console.log(contactdetail);

  }
  $scope.clearData = function () {
    window.localStorage.clear();

  }
});
```

Comment: "...print out the data..." - do you mean to the console log or on your web page? If you mean the console log, it looks like you already do that... unless you mean in a string format?

Comment: I mean on my webpage, in a string format. so i can have the diffrent values in the array in some sort of list.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, I dont think you will be able to get much help unless you clean it up a little.

To print out the data (for debugging, usually) you could just add `{{contactinfo|json}}` somewhere in your html.

To actually display the data for use on the webpage the following should work for you.

```html
<div ng-repeat="contact in contactinfo track by $index">
    <div>Name: {{contact.name}}</div>
    <div>Phone: {{contact.phone}}</div>
    <div>Email: {{contact.email}}</div>
</div>
```

I think that some of that logic might be better split into a factory, too. Something like this maybe...?

```js
var contactFactory = angular.module('contactFactory', []);

contactFactory.factory('contactInfo', ['$window', function ($window) {
    var id = id_counter = 1;
    var contacts = [];

    function addContact(name, phone, email) {
        id_counter += 1;
        contacts.push({
          name: name,
          phone: phone,
          email: email,
          sort_id: id_counter
        });
        saveData();
    }

    function saveData(contactInfo) {
        $window.localStorage.setItem('contactinfo', angular.fromJson(contacts));
    }

    function loadData() {
        contacts = angular.toJson($window.localStorage.getItem('contactinfo'));
        return contacts;
    }

    function clearData() {
        $window.localStorage.removeItem('contactinfo');
    }

    return {
        addContact: addContact,
        saveData: saveData,
        loadData: loadData,
        clearData: clearData
    };
}]);

var app = angular.module('yourAppName', ['contactFactory']);

app.controller('createPerson', ['$scope', 'contactInfo', function ($scope, contactInfo) {
  $scope.editorEnabled = false;
      $scope.disableEditor = function() {
        $scope.editorEnabled = false;
      };
      $scope.enableEditor = function() {
        $scope.editorEnabled = true;
      };

  $scope.contactinfo = [
    {name: 'test', phone: 1231, email: 'asd@asd.com'}
  ];

  $scope.saveData = function () {
    contactInfo.addContact($scope.contactName, $scope.contactPhone, $scope.contactEmail);
    $scope.editorEnabled = false;
  }
  $scope.loadData = contactInfo.loadData;
  $scope.clearData = contactInfo.clearData;
}]);
```

Comment: Thank you the track by $index is working, but it only shows what i have in the $scope.contactinfo, but not what I'm saving locally. When i'm adding the ['contactFactory'] to my module(var app = angular.module('phonebookApp', ['ionic'] )), the app is not working at all? I haven't really learned about factorys i will go read up on it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Casper I didn't test that factory code so it might not be perfect. In your load function, `$scope.loadData `, you are loading to a variable that isnt used anywhere else. You need to put it on the scope somewhere. The easiest way would be to replace your console.log with `$scope.contactinfo = contactdetail`

Comment: I've replaced the console.log with the scope, but how would i go about in the view, so it list all the objects there are?

Comment: After you assign the loaded data to the scope variable with `$scope.contactinfo = contactdetail` the same `ng-repeat` snippet I posted above will work. It should update automatically on load, too.

Comment: Hmm it dosen't unfortunately it only shows the one i put into the array myself in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has wrapper for window, which should be used inside your code. There is also ngStorage module or many available solutions which are dealing with browser storage in Angular way. Moreover Angular has functions like `angular.toJson()` and `angular.fromJson()`. If e.g. `jsonObj` is JSON array then `var obj = angular.fromJson(jsonObj)` gives you JavaScript array. If `jsonObj` has `array` property inside then you should go with: `var jsArray = angular.fromJson(jsonObj).array`.